# Terminal profile dynamically change on SSH sessions

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, console, gnome

I'm using [Gnome Terminal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal) on Ubuntu.

When I use a terminal, I would expect to change the colors (profile in Gnome terminal) when I'm connected to a remote host via SSH.

Terminal profile is normal, if I'm SSH somewhere the profile of the terminal should change, If I exit the remote host the terminal come back to normal.

Do you know a simple way to achieve this ?

PS: On Gnome Terminal you can create profiles but I want them to dynamically change on ssh sessions

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: I Finally found this solution using a simple alias

##### Create a new profile `gnome-terminal`, here called `REMOTE`

```bash
alias ssh="gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=REMOTE -- 'ssh'"
```

### or

Thanks to this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403750/1590990) I discovered [GNOME Console](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/console) which is a different project than [GNOME Terminal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal).

```bash
sudo apt install gnome-console
```

This one satisfies all my needs:

- turns red when ‘root mode’ (sudo/su/pkexec) is active in the terminal
- turns purple when ‘remote mode’ (ssh is in use)